# volatile register int

Tags: c++, c, volatile

Имеет ли смысл такая запись?

```
volatile register int x;
```

С одной стороны, она [компилируется](//ideone.com/fj1xLU), а с другой - я тут вспоминаю и вроде бы `register` не заставляет компилятор размещать переменную в регистре, а лишь даёт рекомендацию, которую компилятор в праве проигнорировать? И вообще, эти два требования (volatile и register) независимы или как-то взаимодействуют?

PS: Идея заставить компилятор отключить все оптимизации, связанные с переменной, но при этом держать её в регистре с целью замера производительности.

Comment: `register` остался в языке как зарезервированное слово, которое ничего не делает. Что тут вообще планируется мерять?

Comment: @VTT, разве? А в какой момент? В VS2010 оно ещё работало.

Comment: Еще в С++11 его перевили в разряд устаревших.

Comment: Интересно, никогда не задумывался, надо asm код посмотреть

Comment: @VTT, и реально компиляторы его игнорируют? А если про более ранние стандарты говорить?

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю. Мне представляется, что `register` работал подобно `inline` - может быть когда-то где-то это действительно воспринималось как рекомендация, но потом утратило всякий смысл. Собственно его поэтому и убрали.

Comment: [Тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) написано, что `register` вообще выкинули из С++17, а до этого было *"hints to the compiler to place the object in the processor's register"*. Еще, оказывается в С (но не в С++) `register` запрещает взятие адреса.

Comment: @VTT, вон пишут, что в Си++11 он стал deprecated, но всё ещё мог использоваться как подсказка компилятору, а вот в Си++17, похоже, вообще убрали ключевое слово. Не понимаю как так, это же обратную совместимость должно поломать, не?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ну вообще логично. Как из регистра сделать адрес в памяти? Если ты как-то реально используешь адрес (и ничего не заинлайнится), то переменная уже в регистре лежать не может.

Comment: В С++17 ключевое слово осталось, но как storage class specifier использовать его больше нельзя. VS2019 в режиме конформного C++17 на такую запись выдает `warning C5033:  'register' is no longer a supported storage class`, gcc аналогично, а вот clang уже дает ошибку.

Comment: @VTT, по ссылке сказано _"In C++, unlike C, variables cannot be declared register. (since C++17)"_ - т. е. я так понимаю, вообще синтаксически нельзя? Я неправильно понимаю, или компиляторы решили отнестись помягче стандарта к этому изменению?

Comment: Ну видимо отнеслись помягче. Хотя уже 8 лет прошло, можно было бы весь затронутый код и подобновить, и компиляторам можно было бы смело выдавать именно ошибку. Тем более, что `register` был относительно малоиспользуемой фичей. Ну мне вообще С++ представляется крайне фривольным языком, так что ничего удивительного.

Comment: Эксперимент с gcc/g++ 7.4.0 показал, что компилятор для -O3 игнорирует `register`, что с ним, что без, на каждой итерации переменная читается из памяти, а потом пишется в нее

Comment: @avp, это при наличии `volatile` или без? А `-O3` вообще как-то влиять должен?

Comment: @Qwertiy, оба варианта --  `volatile register long s1;` и `volatile long s2` производят одинаковый ассемблерный код / -O3 это высокий уровень оптимизации, с ним  код цикла с `long s3` (без `volatile`) использует только регистры

Comment: @avp, `volatile register int foo asm("eax")` ведёт себя более интересно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а так можно? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy, в расширениях gcc... если верить документации, то это тоже не гарантирует, что переменная будет всегда в этом регистре, кроме как в ассемблерных вставках, но похоже оно сдвигает какие-то эвристики... и да, имя переменной надо не забыть... а ещё, документация настойчиво рекомендует этого не делать...

Answer (score 5):

> И вообще, эти два требования (volatile и register) независимы или как-то взаимодействуют?

Да, независимы:

- `volatile` — это *квалификатор типа* (*type qualifiers*), он говорит компилятору, что делать, когда переменной что-то присваивают (когда она является *l-value*). Другие — это `const` и `restrict` (в C99+).
- `register` — это *спецификатор класса памяти* (*storage-class specifier*). Он говорит компилятору, где разместить память под переменную.  Другие — это `static`, `extern`, `auto` (в С), а также де-стандарто `typedef` (не по смыслу, но так было проще описать грамматику языка). Оных в объявлении переменной может быть не более одного.

> `register` не заставляет компилятор размещать переменную в регистре, а лишь даёт рекомендацию, которую компилятор в праве проигнорировать?

Да, именно так, разве что, строго говоря, стандарт говорит, даже не «размещать в регистре», а «обеспечить максимально быстрый доступ к ней». Но для большинства компиляторов это **очень слабая** подсказка, которая принимается оптимизатором, как говорят, чуть чаще, чем никогда.

В силу практически полной бесполезности использование этого ключевого слова объявили нежелательным (*deprecated*) в С++11 и полностью выкинули из последнего стандарта (С++17).

На вскидку, на сегодня я бы сказал, что практическая польза от этого слова только одна — низкоуровневый код в gcc с использованием [расширенных ассемблерных вставок](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm), чтобы [привязать](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Register-Variables.html#Explicit-Register-Variables) её к конкретному регистру.

> PS: Идея заставить компилятор отключить все оптимизации, связанные с переменной, но при этом держать её в регистре с целью замера производительности.

Почти наверняка не рабочая идея — даже если компилятор действительно разместит переменную в регистре, он не будет уважать **все** действия с переменной, а только сохранение и загрузку в неё данных, что может смазать результаты замеров.

Для таких тонких целей единственный выход — использовать ассемблерные вставки. Во всех противных случаях нельзя контролировать, что именно заменяется.

Comment: Дверь может быть: в квартиру, в комнату, на балкон; а также деревянная, железная, стеклянная; а ещё с замком или без замка. Это три разные категории. Но если я скажу "стеклянная дверь в квартиру без замка", то вероятно, это будет какой-то фигнёй? Количество таких дверей - примерно 0. Разные категории не обязательно независимы друг от друга.

Comment: Кстати, а какие ещё действия можно делать, кроме сохранения и загрузки данных? А, кажется понял. Если я делаю `z = x * y;`, то компилятор гарантированно оставит чтение `x`, но может спокойно выкинуть считывание `y`, умножение и присваивание. Так?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я имею в виду, что компилятор может, например для `volatile int i; i++;` использовать вместо обычного `inc $i` что-то вроде `mov $i,%rax; inc %rax;mov %rax, $i;` — вчера экспериментировал и получал такие странные результаты  на godbolt'е, но стабильности добиться не удалось, правда стабильности не добился, так что поделиться нечем... по поводу полезности — ИМХО очевидно, что она близка к нулю иначе самого вопроса не было бы... разве что может использоваться на какой-то странной архитектуре, где эта переменная будет привязана к какому-то специальному регистру...

Answer (score 1):

Си стандарт 6.7.1 :

> A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class
>   specifier register suggests that access to the object be as fast as
>   possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is
>   implementation-defined.
>
> The implementation may treat any register declaration simply as an
>   auto declaration. However, whether or not addressable storage is
>   actually used, the address of any part of an object declared with
>   storage-class specifier register cannot be computed, either explicitly
>   (by use of the unary & operator as discussed in 6.5.3.2) or implicitly
>   (by converting an array name to a pointer as discussed in
>   6.3.2.1). Thus, the only operators that can be applied to an array declared with storage-class specifier register are sizeof and
>   _Alignof.

Переменная со знаком `register` намекает компилятору работать с ней как можно быстрее. Адрес регистровой переменной брать нельзя. Но компиляторы могут реализовать переменную в памяти, а могут в процессорных ячейках.

Си стандарт 6.7.3 :

> An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways
>   unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects.
>   Therefore any expression referring to such an object shall be
>   evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine, as
>   described in 5.1.2.3. Furthermore, at every sequence point the value
>   last stored in the object shall agree with that prescribed by the
>   abstract machine, except as modified by the unknown factors mentioned
>   previously. 134) What constitutes an access to an object that has
>   volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined.
>
> A volatile declaration may be used to describe an object corresponding
>   to a memory-mapped input/output port or an object accessed by an
>   asynchronously interrupting function. Actions on objects so declared
>   shall not be ‘‘optimized out’’ by an implementation or reordered
>   except as permitted by the rules for evaluating expressions.

Переменная со знаком `volatile` имеет способность менять значение неизвестным компилятору способом. По-этому компилятор постоянно читает и записывает значения в память.

Одновременная декларация `register volatile` указывает обязательно записывать значения. А планы `register` всего-лишь были увеличить скорость, но не место хранения.

Ваши надежды могут быть реализованы наверно только ассемблером.

Comment: По крайней мере gcc/g++ 7.4.0 при наличии **volatile** размещает переменную в памяти, а не регистрах, независимо от оптимизации